# I tried to cancel my token transaction

Tags: transactions

I just try to cancel my token transaction, I followed the instructions from [here](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html) more than 1 day and my transaction are always getting reset.

How to cancel that two transactions

1. transaction to exchange, but that got pending and always reseting too
2. cancel the transaction number 1, the problem is same always reseting too
3. I try again to sending my token to exchange nothing happened yet
   https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdd462729f2e2656237cbe77d532a1760320a95d779aec1d294a85197195c1c38

In this case I forget the number 1 tx transaction.

I hope you understand, sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

You provided this as your transaction 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdd462729f2e2656237cbe77d532a1760320a95d779aec1d294a85197195c1c38

However looking at that transaction there is nothing on the blockchain related to that transaction id therefore the transaction never got mined, never made it to the blockchain and any ETH/Token will still be in your wallet.

Comment: Correct, that my transaction, and I have canceled that transaction already.

in other problems i also have 2 transactions which that still pending and always getting reset.


https://etherscan.io/tx/0xab0e662bd367adeae4ed9cc014233591aa85180e0ae57c2d7bdc2ce7f55ddac6

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1a95b271b0535d15fa49932daba31ba612b52946


i've been waiting for 4 days, but yeah as i said before that always getting reset.